# mediaMetaDataRetriver.setDataSource(string path) not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mediametadataretriever

```
m_mediaMetadataRetriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
m_mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(p_videoPath)
m_bitmap = m_mediaMetadataRetriever.frameAtTime
```

I am trying to get the frame from a video that I recorded using MediaStore.Action_Video_Capture. The video is stored at a location `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/PXL_1345657.mp4`

But after running the above code the bitmap is coming null and setDataSource is showing an IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 0):

There is another overload method that only worked for me: `setDataSource(Context, Uri)`. You should obtain Uri of the file (with proper permissions) and pass it to the method with according context.

Comment: can you shed a bit more light on the approach

Comment: How have you defined path to the file? please, provide more info about the way, and I'll try to help you with specific approach.

Comment: E.g., if you are using standard camera app for video recording, then in onActvityResult you will get Intent with the Uri of the file recorded